# How to copy a model in django with small differences in Meta using a function?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that has lots of models, and lots of relations. I have got a job to create a new model with different name and db_table meta using a function that has a parameter to model that will be copied. I should change `ManyToMany` and `ForeignKey` references to newly created/will created new models.

I tried DynamicModels in Django with type(name, (models.Model,), attrs), but after some try 'is_relation' attribute error came into action. create_model function will be used to do this action.

```py
Class C(models.Model):
  q = models.CharField(max_length=20)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.q

Class A(models.Model):
  x = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  y = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Class B(models.Model):
  z = models.ForeignKey(A)
  t = models.ManyToManyField(C)
  w = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def create_model(model):
  pass
```

I have classes like this which I described in summary. I should create new classes like C1, A1, B1 with different db_table `metas`. Also, I should change `ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany` fields to A1 and C1.

I can add my create_model function if you request it.

Comment: So you want to create model dynamically?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam my models are complicated compared to [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)

Comment: What is the error exactly you got after trying with type(name, (base_models,), attr)?

Comment: AttributeError: 'AutoField' object has no attribute 'is_relation' @AshrafulIslam